Why does expansion tank not fix water hammer type noise?
New to me old ('62) house with a fair amount of remodeling, gas hot water heater. When I moved in no expansion tank and water pressure would shoot up to > 110psi, also found the house pressure valve was defective.
Both are fixed, a new expansion tank set at 60psi (I just checked it again), and replacement pressure valve hanging right at 60psi.  I continually monitor the pressure with Home Assistant and it nicely hangs near 60psi with some variation.   All good... except.
When water is used, hot or cold, especially turning off or on several times (washing machine does that a lot) I get a clear knock from the closet with the HW Heater (to be fair it is a distribution point for lots of pipes, and the expansion tank is there also, so the HW tank being there may not be relevant). So far I cannot tell where the noise originates, i.e. which specific pipe or fixture.
It is not terribly loud, only audible from within 20' or so of that closet.
My question is twofold --
Does it do any actual HARM, is the sudden pulse likely to harm pex or copper (I have a lot of both) with repeated stress?  Or is it just a human annoyance? If it does no harm I simply do not care.
But the bigger question, for curiosity if nothing else, is -- why isn't the expansion tank (which is on the cold supply side of the HW Heater, which is a 55g gas conventional tank) acting to prevent the hammer?  It's brand new and properly inflated (water off, pressure depleted, air gauge reads 60psi). I am sure it is functional as I can see the suppressed rise after major hot water usage with faucets off. It would seem to be capable of much more suppression than a Tee style device (which I do not have), but... bang, bang...

Yes, these blows can produce high pressure, high frequency waves that may destroy many components like sealings, gauges or weak connections.
They should be avoided.
The expansion tank is too sluggy, too inert to react to those pressure waves. It is meant for slow pressure changes, may be up to 2 Hertz only.
But those hammer blows contain tens or even hundreds of Hertz or more, far above the maximum frequency response of expansion tanks.
This is also why they can be heard in contrast to the very slow expansion by heating - most people can't hear below 16 Hz.
Besides this, the pressure wave can destroy already something on the way to the expansion tank, and even the tank itself.

You should find this paper interesting as it talks about the propagation of the wave in the water and its speed (not frequency) : http://www.fluidmechanics.co.uk/hydraulic-calculations/water-hammer-2/#:~:text=The%20sonic%20velocity%20is%20also,lower%20than%20200%20m%2Fs.

Simply because the pipes have the possibility to vibrate or move before the pressure wave (which is what water hammer is) gets to the expansion tank.
The solution will be to fit a water hammer arrestor close to the source generating the water hammer.
Another solution, if the source is a tap or similar, is to fit a tap that cannot be closed so rapidly. One valve or tap that can cause water hammer is the quarter turn type - as they can be shut so quickly.

Yeah, except that the worst offender is my washing machine, second worst are toilets, so not so easy to change the taps.  But understood, thanks.

@Linwood then fit the arrestors... And you accept the answer with no solution?

I would accept both but I do not know how.  The first solution was explicit in terms of frequency response. The solution of a hammer arrestor is obvious, the question is why it is needed with an expansion tank already present.

@Linwood as I clearly stated : that the expansion tank is too far away...

I guess I will find out.  My inclination is to put the arrestor near where the noise manifests and not go all over the house placing them on other devices (toilets, washer, etc.).  If that fails, and I need to go to those devices, you will of course be right. My gut tells me that the bladder in the expansion tank cannot move fast enough to absorb the impulse, but that an arrestor in that vicinity (will leave it to a plumber to decide where) will solve it.  I'd add one myself but have no pex crimp tools and not worth buying for a one-off (though I've said that many times in the past).

Water hammer is caused by the inertia of the mass of water in the pipe that leads to the valve that closes too quickly - so the moving column of water in the pipe meets a suddenly closed valve, causing the pressure to spike. Thus, the arrestor needs to be positioned as close as possible to the suddenly-closing valve (the solenoid valves in washing machines are classic examples of fast-closing valves.) If you put it at the other end, the pressure-spike will occur at the valve end of the pipe and be reflected back down it until it finally meets the improperly located arrestor.

@Ecnerwal probably why I wrote "fit a water hammer arrestor close to the source generating the water hammer"

For washing machines, there are arrestors with male and female hose threads that can be connected to either end of the washing machine's hoses. The end nearest the machine would be ideal. No plumber required. And Solar Mike, @Linwood clearly needs to hear it enough ways that they "get it."

Your argument seems solid but I did some listening today, and there is no noise anywhere, from any on/off source, other than one pipe inside that closet with the HW Heater (it is the old water feed, that tee's off to the pressure tank and a pressure sensor).  The noise is from that pipe jumping in and out of the wall, slightly, probably banging against a stud behind it.   I wish I had a photo from before, but I THINK there was an arrestor on the pipe before the plumber redid that section in pex for the tank and sensor.  But all the energy-as-noise is definitely from there.

So... a brief followup.  I did order 2 clothes washer arrestors after seeing the hoses to them visibly moving (though soundlessly).  I installed them tonight, and with nothing else using water ran the washer. They still move though less, but the noise in the water heater closet (50' or so away maybe) still bangs loudly.  Maybe not as loudly, but bangs.  So... that helped, but I am still thinking I need them in that closet.  I can't explain why, but ... well, I tried that alternative.  And yes, they are up and full of air, right on the back of the washer.
